# Slide with input radio properly on css

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button, slide

How could I get my images to slide without staking on top of each other?. Say I have 3 images in inside a dis element and an input radio type element for each corresponding images> I could make it slide when clicking on it but the first image has the other two on top of it same with the second one

```
 <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1"/>
 <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2"/>
 <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3"/>

  <div className="slide first">
                <img src={Image} alt="" id='guitar'/>
            </div>
            <div className="slide second">
                <img src={Image2} alt="" id='bass'/>
            </div>
            <div className="slide third">
            <img src={Image3 }alt="" id='drum' />
            </div>

  <div className="navigation-manual">
            <label for='radio1' className='manual-btn'></label>
            <label for='radio2' className='manual-btn'></label>
            <label for='radio3' className='manual-btn'></label>
           </div>
```

```
#guitar{
    width: 1500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;

}
#bass{
    width: 1500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    
}

#drum{
    width: 1500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}


#radio1:checked ~ .first{
    margin-left: -10;
}

#radio2:checked ~ .second{
    margin-left: -50%;
}

#radio3:checked ~ .third{
    margin-left: -90%;
}
```

Here are images where I show what I mean with "images stacked up on each other "  the third one is fully displayed because is the last one but I want to achieve the same with the first 2 others. I what to be able to show the entire image and hide the other 2 when clicking the inputs. Any suggestion?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

I would highly suggest the use of **Bootstrap**. Here you can plug in these ready made components into your website.

You can use a **Carousel** in your project. Just change the **src** into your own images then it should work.

Code example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="guitar.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="bass.png" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="drums.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tell me what you think. Thanks!